# How can I see pdf file directly from my windows phone 8.1 app, not from other pdf reader?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, winrt-component

How can I see pdf file directly from my windows phone 8.1 app, not from other pdf reader? Is there free component?

Comment: What do you mean by directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no build-in PDF control (like in W8.1). ComponentOne package have PDF viewer and Radaee as well, both are $500